# Inner Join on Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

There is a table name `Product`:

```
|ProductID|ProductName|
  1            abc
  2            xyz
```

and there is another table `Product Status`.

The column `Result` in the below has three values:

```
Result
Value | Meta
 0        Not checked
 1        Failed
 2        Passed  

ProductCheckList
ID(AutoGenerated) | ProductID(Foreign Key) | Stage | Result |
    1                  1                         1      1
    2                  1                         2      2
```

In this table every product has to go through five different stages. If the product passes all the stages then the product is given quality checked status , If the product fails any on of the stages is is given as quality failed and send back to production.

I have to show a list of all the products with there quality status and depending on its quality state highlight the row with different row color. We are using Entity Framework and I am new to this.

I have thought of making a wrapper class for this.

```
Public class ProductWrapper
{
    public Product product{get;set;}
    Public string QualityStatus{get;set;}
    public  string BgColor {get;set;}
}
```

I am writing this LINQ query:

```
UtilitiesEntities context = new UtilitiesEntities();
            List<ProductWrapper> wrapperList = new List<ProductWrapper>();
            var request = from product in context.Product
                          join productCheck in context.ProductCheckList
                          on product.productId equals productCheck .productID
                           // may be do group by or something i get the result and assign the values.
                          select new List<ProductWrapper>
                          {

                          };
```

I am not able to write the query and add the where condition to fetch the result a list of wrapper class to pass to my view with the desired result.

Comment: What is "QualityStatus" and where is it in the database?

Comment: @vorrtex it is a calculated field based on field result ProductCheckList table. If for a product all the five stages have value 2 in result column the "QualityStatus" will be Passed same for failed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your request, you want something like this:

```
string goodQualityColor = "Green";
string badQualityColor = "Red";
string notCheckedColor = "Gray";
string notCheckedStatus = "Not Checked";
string failedStatus = "Failed";
string passedStatus = "Passed";

Dictionary<int,string> results= new Dictionary<int,string>();
results.Add(2,goodQualityColor);
results.Add(1,badQualityColor);
results.Add(0,notCheckedColor);

Dictionary<int,string> qualityStatuses = new Dictionary<int,string>();
results.Add(2,passedStatus);
results.Add(1,failedStatus);
results.Add(0,notCheckedStatus);

var request = (from product in context.Product
              join productCheck in context.ProductCheckList
              on product.productId equals productCheck.productID
              select new
              {
                 Product = product,
                 QualityStatus = productCheck.Result,
                 Result = productCheck.Result
              }).ToList();

var finalResults = (from req in request
                    select new ProductWrapper
                    {
                      Product = req.Product,
                      QualityStatus = qualityStatuses.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Key == req.QualityStatus).Value,
                      BgColor = results.FirstOrDefault (s => s.Key == req.Result).Value  
                    }).ToList<ProductWrapper>();
```

Comment: it is a calculated field based on field result ProductCheckList table. If for a product all the five stages have value 2 in result column the "QualityStatus" will be Passed same for failed.

Comment: thank you for the answer. one thing is if any product passed four stages and failed in one than it is treated as failed but by your methotd it is passed.

Comment: @ankur Mmm..I have some trouble now in checking again the queries. Anyway, in a first check, I found a little mistake in the first query. Check again its execution please. I will check the queries soon.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an outer join using the into keyword and then do my statusCheck in the select part.
Could would look something like this :

```
var data = (from product in context.Product
            join productCheck in context.ProductCheckList on product.productId equals productCheck.productID into productChecks
            select new ProductWrapper
            {
                product = product,
                passedBool = productChecks.All(pc => pc.Result == 2) && productChecks.Count() == 5
            }).ToList();
```